# Enclave Destruction Sources

Tags: scholomance

This question is a spoiler for the big reveal half-way through the third book. Please don't read any further if you don't want to see the spoilers.

Can each of the disruption or destruction of Enclaves be linked to a specific Maw-Mouth killed during the series.

Bangkok appears to be Maw-Mouth killed in the Library
Salah the small one in the Graduation Hall
The one killed in London is Beijing.

Which Maw-mouth connects to the damage to London?

The general information in the series states that multiple maw-mouths were eaten by Patience and Fortitude each year, and Fortitude itself was eaten by Patience during El's final year in the Scholomance, so it seems clear that a Maw-mouth does not destroy a maw-mouth or damage an enclave when this happens.

Comment: I think the eating by others amalgamated them rather than destroying them - so might expect damage to more than one enclave from killing of some?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three* other Maw-mouths appear in the series:

> the one El destroyed in Mumbai -- this one is clearly underpinning the Dubai enclave.

> **Patience** underpins the Scholomance itself. Patience is absorbed by Orion during the desperate attempt by El to rescue Orion at the beginning of *The Golden Enclaves*, just after Orion pushed her through. Orion carries Patience around inside himself through the story.

For London, this leaves only

> **Fortitude** who wasn't actually  *devoured* by Patience so much as *combined* into a weird Patience-Fortitude  mix.

Recall that

> we hear about the disaster in London right at the beginning of *The Golden Enclaves* while El is in her stupor over having lost Orion

We also learn later that

> El is the **only person on Earth** able to destroy a maw-mouth - even Li Shinfeng kept the core of the maw-mouth he fought to refound the Shanghai Enclave.

During her initial rescue attempt, El

> went into a frenzy of casting "A la mort" via her connection to Orion through the portal to kill the maw-mouth's victims,

and I can only guess

> she got the initial victim who had been at the core of Fortitude, underpinning one of London's foundation points.

---

*well actually

> **Orion** has a maw-mouth built into him; that's how he was able to absorb Patience.